# NodeJS Server crash when request/response.aborted

Tags: node.js, express

When aborting a xmlHttpRequest, sent to a NodeJS-Express server, the server crashes if the request has not been processed finally or the response can't be send, due to a abroted request.

I use a connected-flag to make sure the response is only sent when the connection is up.
I tried to catch these exceptions, but they don't handle the request aborted event:

```
var connected = true;
req.connection.on('close', function () {
    connected = false;
    // code to handle connection abort
});
res.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("response couldn't be sent.");
    connected = false;
});
if(connected)
    res.send(...);

req.connection.removeListener('close', removeCallback);
res.removeListener('error', removeCallback);
```

Are there any events I can look at to take care of the „Error: Request aborted“ exception, which causes the server to crash?

Answer (score 2):

According to the W3C specs, XMLHttpRequest emits a "abort" event.

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-handlers

So basically, you can listen to that event to handle the error, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `request.on('abort', fn)` should work fine for detecting an aborted HTTP request in `node.js`